# NULL-Values when deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, null, deserialization

I try to deserialize different XML docs which are build according to the same schema and yes, I'm a newby to this topic. I managed to retrieve some auto-generated Code from using xsd-files as “type definition language” (VS2013) and for me it looks ok and basically it’s working which means I can start the program. However, there is no output of my program and by debugging it I can see that the most important fields are not populated. Here is the situation (the original generated code and the XML are of course much longer but I cut to the classes which produce the problem):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainDatas 
  xmlns="http://www.myNamespace.com/"
  xmlns:ons="http://www.myOtherNamespace.com/"
  xmlns:aan="http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/">
  <contains>
    <ons:FeatureCollection aan:id="UHL">
      <aan:boundedBy>999.9</aan:boundedBy>
      <aan:featureMember>
        <myClass1 aan:id="XXX0001">
        </myClass1>
      </aan:featureMember>
        <myClass2 aan:id="XXX0002">
        </myClass2>
      </aan:featureMember>
        <myClass1 aan:id="XXX0003">
        </myClass1>
      </aan:featureMember>
    </ons:FeatureCollection>
  </contains>
</mainDatas>
```

C# (auto-generated):

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.myNamespace.com/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("mainDatas", Namespace="http://www.myNamespace.com/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class mainDatas
{
    private mainDatasContains containField;

    public mainDatasContains contain
    {
        get
        {
            return this.containField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.containField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.myNamespace.com/")]
public partial class mainDatasContains
{

    private FeatureCollectionType1 featureCollectionField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.myOtherNamespace.com/")]
    public FeatureCollectionType1 FeatureCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this.featureCollectionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.featureCollectionField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="FeatureCollectionType", Namespace="http://www.myOtherNamespace.de/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("FeatureCollection", Namespace="http://www.myOtherNamespace.de/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FeatureCollectionType1
{

    private string lockIdField;

    private FeaturePropertyType[] featureMemberField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lockId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lockIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lockIdField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("featureMember")]
    public FeaturePropertyType[] featureMember
    {
        get
        {
            return this.featureMemberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.featureMemberField = value;
        }
    }       
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("featureMember", Namespace="http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FeaturePropertyType
{

  private AbstractFeatureType itemField;

  private bool ownsField;

  public FeaturePropertyType()
  {
      this.ownsField = false;
  }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DynamicFeature", typeof(DynamicFeatureType))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FeatureCollection", typeof(FeatureCollectionType))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Observation", typeof(ObservationType))]
  public AbstractFeatureType Item
  {
      get
      {
          return this.itemField;
      }
      set
      {
          this.itemField = value;
      }
  }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
  public bool owns
  {
      get
      {
          return this.ownsField;
      }
      set
      {
          this.ownsField = value;
      }
  }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(myClass1))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(myClass2))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/", IsNullable=true)]
public abstract partial class AbstractFeatureType
{

    private BoundingShapeType boundedByField;

    private LocationPropertyType itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public BoundingShapeType boundedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this.boundedByField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.boundedByField = value;
        }
    }
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://myNamespace.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("myClass1", Namespace="http://www.myNamespace.com/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class myClass1 : AbstractFeatureType
{
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("MSBuild", "12.0.30723.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://myNamespace.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("myClass2", Namespace="http://www.myNamespace.com/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class myClass2 : AbstractFeatureType
{
}
```

Sorry for posting that much auto-generated code. I tried to omitt as much as possible but since I'm quite clueless I'm not sure what is necessary and what not.

And now my piece of work:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mainDatas));
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@".\myData.xml");
mainDatas dataObject = (mainDatas)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

FeaturePropertyType[] allObjects = dataObject.contain.FeatureCollection.featureMember;

foreach(FeaturePropertyType feature in allObjects)
{
   if (feature.Item != null && feature.Item.GetType() == typeof(myClass1))
   {
        this.doSomething((myClass1)feature.Item));
   }
   else
   {
        this.doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

While debugging it shows me that allObjects contains 3 items of type FeaturePropertyType (i.e. the number of myClass1 and myClass2 in the xml-sheet as suspected) but the property Item of these items is null.

When I searched in the Internet many people suggested that it might be a problem with the namespaces. So I experimented a little bit with it changing it back and forth but without success. And I don't think it's a good idea to change to much in the auto-generated code, anyways.

I would be glad if anyone could give me some suggestions about this issue.

Greetings
TM

EDIT:
I had to edit my code because I forgot to write the inheritance of AbstractFeatureType by myClass1 and myClass2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainDatas mainDatas = new MainDatas() {
                contains = new MainDatasContains() {
                    featureCollection = new FeatureCollection(){
                        id = "UHL",
                        boundedBy = 999.9,
                        featureMembers = new List<FeatureMember>() {
                            new FeatureMember() {
                                myClass1 = new MyClass1() {
                                    id = "XXX0001"
                                }
                            },
                            new FeatureMember() {
                                myClass2 = new MyClass2() {
                                    id = "XXX0001"
                                }
                            },
                            new FeatureMember() {
                                myClass1 = new MyClass1() {
                                    id = "XXX0003"
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            };


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainDatas));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("aan", "http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/");
            ns.Add("ons", "http://www.myOtherNamespace.com/");
            ns.Add("", "http://www.myNamespace.com/");

            serializer.Serialize(writer, mainDatas, ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainDatas));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            MainDatas newMainDatas = (MainDatas)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("mainDatas", Namespace = "http://www.myNamespace.com/")]   
    public class MainDatas
    {

        [XmlElement("contains")]
        public MainDatasContains contains { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("contains")]
    public class MainDatasContains
    {

        [XmlElement("FeatureCollection", Namespace = "http://www.myOtherNamespace.com/")]
        public FeatureCollection featureCollection { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FeatureCollection")]
    public class FeatureCollection
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id", Namespace = "http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("boundedBy", Namespace = "http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
        public double boundedBy { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("featureMember", Namespace = "http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
        public List<FeatureMember> featureMembers { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("featureMember")]
    public class FeatureMember
    {
        [XmlElement("myClass1")]
        public MyClass1 myClass1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("myClass2")]
        public MyClass2 myClass2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("myClass1")]
    public class MyClass1
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id", Namespace = "http://www.andAnotherNamespace.com/")]
        public string id { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("myClass2")]
    public class MyClass2
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, jdweng. I will try out your suggestion and share my results, soon.

Comment: Hi again, jdweng! Sorry for the late reply, but I was occupied by some other work I had to accomplish first. Well, I tried your suggestions but I see, it's not simply change on or two lines but I have to change a lot in the auto-generated code (which is much longer than the piece above). For that reason I decided to begin from the scratch since I only need few informations contained in the XML and I will try it by using LINQ to XML. Maybe it's not a good idea to use auto-generated code, anyways. But thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: My code is equivalent to auto-generated code.  The auto generated pseudo ops aren't needed.  So I just put in the minimum amount of code to get things working.  I haven't fully tested my code, but will do a little later today if you have any issues.

Comment: I added tested code.  You had an open tag instead of closing tag.  The XML format is slightly different.  The tag names generated is slightly different.  But it still reads your original format.